# CakePHP Form Input - prevent default?

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers

I have this in my view

```
<?=$this->Form->create('Company')?>
     <?=$this->Form->input('Company.company_category_id')?>
     <?=$this->Form->input('Company.county')?>
     <?=$this->Form->input('Company.name')?>
     // Here i intend to insert all model fields in order to export them
     <?=$this->Form->input('ExportField.company_category_id', array('label' => 'Categorie', 'type' => 'checkbox', 'options' => null))?>
     // ...
<?=$this->Form->end('Submit')?>
```

My problem is that the helper is "autoMagically" consider that ExportField.{field} as being the form's main model field (Company in this case).

I can use a workaround to resolve this, but I want to know if I can force it somehow maintaining this approach.

Thank's!

Comment: What do you mean by 'the form's main model field'?

Comment: The one you pass to the create method, as first parameter.

Comment: That should work fine as you have it.  Post the HTML code it generates?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring model in:

```
<?=$this->Form->create('Company')?>
```

As cake doc says, [All parameters are optional](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html). Try with:

```
<?=$this->Form->create()?>
```

Comment: You should be able to pass the model, then specify a field of a different model without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'action_name')?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.company_category_id')?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.county')?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.name')?>
 // Here i intend to insert all model fields in order to export them
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('ExportField.company_category_id', array('label' => 'Category', 'type' => 'checkbox'))?>
 // ...
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit')?>
```

If you would use `ModelName` as null as a first argument in `$this->Form->create()` method, then you can easily achieve the same you needed.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but I have tested that and it behaves the same way.